# Yii2 GridView связанные поля

Tags: yii2, gridview

Вывожу данные через виджет

```
$dataProvider = new ActiveDataProvider([
    'query' => \common\models\Pay::find(),
    'pagination' => [
        'pageSize' => 10,
    ],
]);
echo GridView::widget([
    'dataProvider' => $dataProvider,
    'columns' => [
        [
            'attribute' => 'data',
            'format' => ['date', 'php:d.m.Y']
        ],
        'user.email',
        [
            'class' => 'yii\grid\ActionColumn',
            'buttons' => [
                'delete' => function ($url, $model, $key) {
                    return '<a href="/admin/pay/delete/'.$key.'" class="btn btn-danger"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-trash" aria-hidden="true"></span></a>';
                },
                'update' => function ($url, $model, $key) {
                    return '<a href="/admin/pay/edit/'.$key.'" class="btn btn-info"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-pencil" aria-hidden="true"></span></a>';
                },
                'view' => function ($url, $model, $key) {
                    return '';
                },
            ]
        ]
    ],
]);
```

в таблице `Pay` есть поле `user_id`, которое связано с таблицей `User`. Поэтому в `columns` я пишу

```
'user.email',
```

но мне выдает ошибку, что в `Pay` нет поля `user`.
Если я напишу

```
'user_id.email'
```

ничего не выводит. Помогите разобраться

Comment: а в модели Pay есть релейшен getUser?

Comment: уже есть) спасибо, как раз нашел решение

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Надо добавить метод

```
public function getUser()
{
    return $this->hasOne(User::className(), ['id' => 'user_id']);
}
```